# Does the spell Unseen Servant count as taking the "Help" action for Artificers or any crafters building or repairing things?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, crafting, helping

Does the spell Unseen Servant count as taking the "Help" action for Artificers or any crafters building or repairing things?

I understand that [Unseen Servant](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/unseen-servant) can do basic tasks, but the spell states:

> The servant can perform simple tasks that a human servant could do, such as fetching things, cleaning, mending, folding clothes, lighting fires, serving food, and pouring wine. Once you give the command, the servant performs the task to the best of its ability until it completes the task, then waits for your next command.

So while not being able to help you build, it can help you fix (mending) things or just assist by retrieving and stowing tools. Is that enough to grant you advantage to you crafting or repair checks?

Answer (score 7):

## No

From the rules on [crafting an item](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/xgte/downtime-revisited#CraftinganItem) (XGtE, p. 128):

> A character needs to be proficient with the tools needed to craft an item and have access to the appropriate equipment. Everyone who collaborates needs to have the appropriate tool proficiency.

An *unseen servant* isn't listed as having any skill proficiencies. At best, you could argue that it might cut down the time needed to craft or repair an item, but that would be a DM call and since the servant only lasts for an hour I wouldn't hope for much.